# Facebook Share Does not Display image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

I found this in javascript console

> *Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.*

when I tried to share a link on Facebook. Here is the [Link](http://www.viewsnepal.com/np/display-content.php?id=331#.U160gYGSyBn). The problem is, the share dialog does not show the image.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite straight-forward.

You have not properly configure the application settings. Make sure you've added the correct link in the **Site Url**